# OpenCV load cascadeClassifier EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm using the "official" opencv2.framework and already setup the wrappers and bridging header etc. I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message and crash when i run the app. I'm working in swift. here is the code from the wrapper file.

What am i doing wrong?

```
#include "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

@implementation OpenCVWrapper : NSObject



+ (UIImage *)processImageWithOpenCV:(UIImage*)inputImage{
Mat mat = [inputImage CVMat];
cv::CascadeClassifier* faceDetector;
// do your processing here
//...

// Load cascade classifier from the XML file
NSString* cascadePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2" ofType:@"xml"];

faceDetector->load([cascadePath UTF8String]);

// Load image with face
//UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lena.png"];
Mat faceImage;
faceImage = mat;
Mat grayImage;
cvtColor(faceImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

//Detect faces
std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
faceDetector->detectMultiScale(grayImage, faces, 1.1, 2,0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30,30));
//Draw all detected faces
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    const cv::Rect& face = faces[i];
    //Get top-left and bottom-right corner points
    cv::Point tl(face.x , face.y);
    cv::Point br = tl + cv::Point(face.width,face.height);

    //draw rectangle around the face
    cv::Scalar magenta = cv::Scalar(255,0,255);
    cv::rectangle(faceImage, tl, br, magenta, 4, 8, 0);


    }

    //show resulting image

    return [UIImage imageWithCVMat:faceImage];

}

@end
```

Comment: First, you're working in Objective C. Second, what does your error say?

Answer (score 2):

I trust you are doing well. Try this wrapper I've written. It's got to do with you creating a pointer to CascadeClassifier and i'm no c++ boffin but just a quick google suggests that the '->' accesses member variables and methods from a pointer and '.' accesses member variables and methods from an instance. Consequently, i'd like to think this is the reason for your bad access error. My wrapper works for me in my project. Hope it works for you!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

@interface VJImageProcessingModule : NSObject

+ (void)startCascadeClassifier;
+ (vector<cv::Rect>)faceDetect:(Mat &)image;
+ (void)drawRectanglesOnFacesForImage:(Mat &)image andFacesRect:(vector<cv::Rect>)faces;

@end

#import "VJImageProcessingModule.h"
@implementation VJImageProcessingModule

static NSString *cascade_name = @"haarcascade_frontalface_default";
static NSString *cascade_name2 = @"haarcascade_frontalface_alt";
static NSString *cascade_name3 = @"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2";
static NSString *cascade_name4 = @"haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree";

static CascadeClassifier cascade_model;

+ (void)startCascadeClassifier
{
NSString *cascade_fp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:cascade_name3 ofType:@"xml"];
cascade_model.load([cascade_fp UTF8String]);
}

+ (vector<cv::Rect>)faceDetect:(Mat &)image
{
if (cascade_model.empty()){[VJImageProcessingModule startCascadeClassifier];};

vector<cv::Rect> faces;
cascade_model.detectMultiScale(image, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30));

return faces;
}

+ (void)drawRectanglesOnFacesForImage:(Mat &)image andFacesRect:(vector<cv::Rect>)faces
{
    for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
    {
     cv::Point pt1(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
     cv::Point pt2((faces[i].x + faces[i].height), (faces[i].y + faces[i].width));
     cv::rectangle(image,pt1,pt2, Scalar(255,0,0),3,8,0);
    }
}

@end
```